# Why does type inference fail here?

Tags: java, generics, intellij-idea, java-8

So, I made this *relatively* simple code, and neither me nor IntelliJ IDEA see anything wrong with it, but javac keels over on the marked line, complaining it can't infer the types:

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class GenericsBreakJavac8 {

    public interface Edge<N> {
        N getNode();
    }

    @FunctionalInterface
    public interface EdgeCreator<N, E extends Edge<N>> {
        E createEdge(N node);
    }

    public static <N> List<Edge<N>> createEdges(List<N> nodes) {
        return createEdges(nodes, DefaultEdge::new); //the deadly line
    }

    //THE NEWLY ADDED LINE (see the edit note)
    public static <N> List<Edge<N>> createEdges2(List<N> nodes) {
        return createEdges(nodes, n -> new DefaultEdge<N>(n));
    }

    public static <N, E extends Edge<N>> List<E> createEdges(List<N> nodes, EdgeCreator<N, E> edgeCreator) {
        return nodes.stream().map(edgeCreator::createEdge).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    public static class DefaultEdge<N> implements Edge<N> {
        private final N node;

        public DefaultEdge(N node) {
            this.node = node;
        }

        @Override
        public N getNode() {
            return node;
        }
    }
}
```

Splitting the problematic line into 2 with explicit types helps, but the type signature is longer than the lambda, completely defeating the purpose of writing the lambda in the first place...

**EDIT:**
If I use an actual lambda instead of a method reference, I get the problem again. See the newly added method above.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`javac` doesn't like that `DefaultEdge` is a raw type.

```
    return createEdges(nodes, DefaultEdge<N>::new);
```

will work as expected.

Comment: You're absolutely right... but it's broken more that I originally explained. Please see my edit if you may.

Comment: @kaqqao `javac` doesn't consider lambda bodies during type inference. It doesn't have enough information to fully figure out the type signature for the `EdgeCreator`. You can either use a method reference, or fully specify the type parameters to `createEdges`: `GenericsBreakJava8.<N, Edge<N>>createEdges(nodes, node -> new DefaultEdge<>(node))`

Comment: I see. Thanks for the elaboration!

Comment: This is actually not considered a raw type: *"For convenience, when the name of a generic type is used to refer to an instance method (where the receiver becomes the first parameter), the target type is used to determine the type arguments. This facilitates usage like `Pair::first` in place of `Pair<String,Integer>::first`. Similarly, a method reference like `Pair::new` is treated like a "diamond" instance creation (`new Pair<>()`). Because the "diamond" is implicit, this form does not instantiate a raw type; in fact, there is no way to express a reference to the constructor of a raw type."*

Comment: Source for that quote is https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.13.1, under the unlabeled examples.

Comment: @Radiodef From that same section:

`If ClassType is a raw type, but is not a non-static member type of a raw type, the candidate notional member methods are those specified in §15.9.3 for a class instance creation expression that uses <> to elide the type arguments to a class.`

`DefaultEdge` is still a raw type in that it doesn't have any type arguments. But the diamond operator is implicit.

Comment: Yes, the specification has written it in that way, but that’s an awful decision. Calling it a raw type creates confusion with “real raw types”, so much that even early Java 8 compilers generated raw type warnings at method references. I would avoid that, even if the specification uses that wording. Calling `DefaultEdge::new` an implicitly typed method reference and `DefaultEdge<N>::new`  an explicitly typed one, makes it much clearer. You can, by the way, also use an explicitly typed lambda expression to solve the problem: `return createEdges(nodes, (N n) -> new DefaultEdge<>(n))`.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to [Jeffrey’s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48512266/2711488), note that your `EdgeCreator` interface doesn’t differ from `Function` in its functionality and `createEdges` doesn’t actually need the problematic type constraints. So one solution is to let `EdgeCreator` extend `Function` to simplify `createEdges`.

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.function.Function;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class GenericsBreakJavac8 {

    public interface Edge<N> {
        N getNode();
    }

    @FunctionalInterface
    public interface EdgeCreator<N, E extends Edge<N>> extends Function<N,E> {
        E createEdge(N node);
        @Override public default E apply(N t) { return createEdge(t); }
    }

    public static <N> List<Edge<N>> createEdges(List<N> nodes) {
        return createEdges(nodes, DefaultEdge::new);
    }

    public static <N> List<Edge<N>> createEdges2(List<N> nodes) {
        return createEdges(nodes, n -> new DefaultEdge<>(n));
    }

    public static <T,R> List<R> createEdges(List<T> nodes, Function<T,R> edgeCreator) {
        return nodes.stream().map(edgeCreator).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    public static class DefaultEdge<N> implements Edge<N> {
        private final N node;

        public DefaultEdge(N node) {
            this.node = node;
        }

        @Override
        public N getNode() {
            return node;
        }
    }
}
```

You could also remove the `EdgeCreator` interface and use `Function<N, E extends Edge<N>>` at places where the constraint needs to be enforced, though, in this code, there is no such place. The constraint will still get enforced when someone tries to use `createEdges(List,Function)`, resp. its result, in a context, where a `List<Edge<SpecificNodeType>>` is required.

Carrying the type constraints over too many code locations just inflates your source code for no benefit.

By the way, in your current code, you don’t even need the `DefaultEdge` class; you could simplify the entire code to

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.function.Function;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class GenericsBreakJavac8 {

    public interface Edge<N> {
        N getNode();
    }

    public static <N> List<Edge<N>> createEdges(List<N> nodes) {
        return createEdges(nodes, n -> () -> n);
    }

    public static <T,R> List<R> createEdges(List<T> nodes, Function<T,R> edgeCreator) {
        return nodes.stream().map(edgeCreator).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for a nice answer! It's true there's plenty of redundancy here, but it's only because I was mercilessly removing code to make this example... My real code has significantly more pieces.